# Does Facebook allow to add posts and update it from another site?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to do a site that allows to read posts from my Facebook account and gives the possibility to add new 'posts', 'comments' to my facebook account. 
Is this possible or allowed by Facebook? Which library should I use ? Possible limitations ?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is based on wordpress, there are a lot of plugins for that.. You can also use a facebook app called RSS Graffiti that posts on your FB account anything you post from the site. 
I don't think by the way that there's something that lets you manage your whole account from outside FB..